# How do i deploy Outlook addin using clickonce

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am struggling finding a good step by step or simple instructions on what is required and how to install an outlook addin using clickonce?

I only need to install it on one computer, the computer is Windows 7, Office 2010, and is sitting on the same home network as mine from which I developed it. It couldn't get much simpler.

I have exported the certificate from the project and imported it onto the client machine and it was successful but when I try and run the clickonce install then it says "Zone not trusted...MyComputer"

I have even used a setup project and generated a .msi to try and install it and it says it is successful but the addin is not loaded ince outlook open..in fact I can not see it at all in the addin manager

all help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook is especially difficult when it comes to security. It doesn't allow for an untrusted source to just install the add-on. However you should be able to do so with accepting the warning at the start.

Can you please give more detail on how you created a security certificate?

The clickone should be straight forward. In the application setting under publish you can set it up there without to much fluffing around.

Here are a few links that might help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

http://gluegood.blogspot.com/2010/07/namecode-classc-sharp.html

http://rextang.net/blogs/work/archive/2009/01/27/6602.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/1666d2b0-a4d0-41e8-ad86-5eab3542de1e

Comment: thanks. These links look good..I have since found a way around the problem using the following http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/07/12/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-1-of-2.aspx this is working for now. I have marked yours as the answer. Thanks for help