# Distributing Outlook Add-In from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield, outlook-addin

I've written an Outlook add-in for our office that I'd like to make available to others for testing.

My Googling has indicated that I should make an InstallShield project in the solution and use that, however my Visual Studio install only opens an InstallShield download page for which there is a dead link.

Following this failure, I attempted to manually add the add-in to Outlook by utilizing the files in the bin directory, but it tells me that it is an invalid add-in.

I'm at a bit of a loss here on how to proceed in making this add-in available for distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use click-once, right click the outlook project in solution explorer and select publish and follow the wizard. The only problem would be that you will need to sign the click-once app because office addins are particular about security.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864297/how-do-i-deploy-outlook-addin-using-clickonce) question has further details.